# react js code is not working on mac os as compare to windows

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native

when i am trying use import demo/hero function in  App .jsx its throwing an error(on mac os 13 but when trying this same code on windows it working my win nodejs ves 18.16.1 but on mac nodejs ver is 20.6.1)

hero.jsx in component

```
const hero = () => {
  return (
    <p>hero</p>
  )
}
export default hero
```

demo.jsx in component

```
const demo = () => {
  return (
    <div>demo</div>
  )
}
export default demo
```

App.jsx

```
**'demo' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
'demo' is defined but never used.eslintno-unused-vars **

import demo from './component/demo' 
import hero from './component/hero'

import './App.css'

const App = () => {
  return (
  <demo />
  )
}
export default App
```

[image: this SS of the problem]

When I am trying use import demo/hero function in  App .jsx its throwing an error(on mac os 13 but when trying this same code on windows it working my win nodejs ves 18.16.1 but on mac nodejs ver is 20.6.1)**help me out**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is not an error. It is a warning of ESLint. For some reason, the ESLint on your Mac will notify you, but on Windows, it does not. Because it is a warning, you still can run the source code without error if you do not `lint` in your start script.

Secondly, The component should be named in Pascal Case.

```
const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <p>hero</p>
  )
}
export default Hero
```